# sencha touch 2 dataview breaded between checkboxfield at top and button at bottom

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, dataview

I've this requirement of giving user provision of subscribing to certain categories. The layout which is to be designed is having -

1. checkbox => at top toggling automatic subscription setting.
2. dataview => at middle, having list of subscriptions and checkbox field.
3. button   => allowing user to update the subscription list.

I've setup the dataview  correctly. Dataview is added as fallows -

```
 xtype: 'dataview',
 itemTpl:'<div style="color:#fff;margin-left: 20px;background: transparent;" class="x-field-checkbox x-field">' +
           '<span style="float:left">{name}</span>' +
           '<span style="float:right">' +
               '<input type="checkbox" class="x-input-el x-input-checkbox" style="display: inline;top:10px">'+
           '</span>'+
         '</div>',
 fields:['name'],
 data:[
    {
      name :'A'
    },
    {
      name :'B'
    },
    {
      name :'C'
    }
```

When I try to add component no 1 and 3 ( specified above in question ) , dataview is not getting displayed. I'm getting checkbox and button only. When I inspect the rendered html, I realize that dataview is not even populating with `data` config. The code I used to add these three components is as fallows -

```
Ext.define("PApp.view.home.Subscription", {
    extend:'Ext.Container',
    xtype:'subscription',
    config: {
        layout:'fit',
        fullscreen:true,
        scrollable:false,
        items: [
            {
                xtype:'container',
                fullscreen:true,
                items:[
                    {
                        xtype:'checkboxfield',
                        name : 'subscriber-setting',
                        label: 'Subscriber',
                        value: 'yes',
                        checked: true
                    },
                   {
                        xtype: 'dataview',
                        itemTpl:'<div style="color:#fff;margin-left: 20px;background: transparent;" class="x-field-checkbox x-field">' +
                                    '<span style="float:left">{name}</span>' +
                                    '<span style="float:right">' +
                                          '<input type="checkbox" class="x-input-el x-input-checkbox"         style="display: inline;top:10px">'+
                                   '</span>'+
                               '</div>',
                        fields:['name'],
                        data:[
                           {
                              name :'A'
                           },
                           {
                              name :'B'
                           },
                           {
                              name :'C'
                           }
                   },
                   {
                              xtype:'button',
                              text:'Update',
                              ui:'action'
                   }
       }
   ]    
   }
});
```

I can't figure out why dataview is not getting displayed ( not even populated with data ). When dataview is not breaded between the checkbox and button, it gets rendered as expected.
   [image: dataview preview]
   and when dataview is breaded ,it looks like this - [image: dataview in between checkboxfield and button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried few things and managed to solve this problem. Mostly, list or dataview are used to display fullscreen content. But in my case, I needed it between two other components.

To make this work, I added following config to parent container -

```
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align : 'stretch'
            },
```

This was not sufficient though. Need to add `flex` config in each component. Without this config, dataview was not being seen. And I was wrong about data not populating indeed it was ( missed it first time since html is deeply nested ). Here's the preview how it looks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try giving some height in css of template or dataview config with `hbox` layout of container

Comment: thanks for direction. `hbox` didn't exactly worked for me but definitely gave me a push where to look at. I've added details in answer. And we should not give `layout` config to dataview explicitly.  It throws warning message saying layout it managed automatically.